# node mysql2 can't access update results

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, mysql2

I'm doing a simple UPDATE with [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) :

```
   UPDATE table1
    SET table1.value1 = ?, table1.value2 = ? 
    WHERE user_id = (
      SELECT user_id 
      FROM user
      WHERE company_id = ?
    )
```

table1 is related to the user table by `user_id`, but I only have the `company_id` so I do a subquery (probably should be a join, but thats another discussion):

```
const [results, buff] = await connection.execute(query, values);
return results
```

However, when accessing the results to make sure there are no errors and that only a single row is updated, `results` returns:

```
  console.log
    ResultSetHeader {
      fieldCount: 0,
      affectedRows: 1,
      insertId: 0,
      info: 'Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0',
      serverStatus: 2,
      warningStatus: 0,
      changedRows: 0
    }
```

But I can't access the values. If I try `results.affectedRows` I get

```
Property 'affectedRows' does not exist on type 'RowDataPacket[] | RowDataPacket[][] | OkPacket | OkPacket[]'.
```

The only way to make it work is to do `results['affectedRows']`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/363#issuecomment-11724676) 
 Git issue thread?

Comment: @PhaniMahesh I'm following their async/await suggestion: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper The only way to get the error is with a try/catch, which I am using. Should I just rely on that for the success of the query?

Answer (score 3):

So I forgot to mention that this is a typescript error, and I was able to fix it by doing:

```
const [results, buff] = await connection.execute(query, values);
const json: any = results;
return json.affectedRows //or whatever property I want
```

This also works:

```
const [results, buff] = await connection.execute(query, values);
return json as any; //then in the calling fuction access the properties I want
```

Comment: I also ended up making an interface for the mysql2 response, so I don't have to use `any`

Comment: could you please update your answer to show the interface you use? I'm stuck working against the RowDataPacket type

Comment: So I'm doing `const [results, buff] = await connection.execute(query, values);
  return results as IUpdateTokens`, and the interface is `interface IUpdateTokens {
  fieldCount?: number,
  affectedRows?: number,
  insertId?: number,
  info?: string,
  serverStatus?: number,
  warningStatus?: number,
  changedRows?: number,
}`

Comment: okay interesting. I still think that would give my implementation trouble with the RowDataPacket... but I'll take a look soon

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same problem and the solution I found is to add return type to connection.execute itself, from types provided by mysql2
`const result = await pool.execute<OkPacket>(query, values);`
I reckon you no longer need it, but hopefully useful to someone else. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps try in this way :

```
let result = await db.execute($sql, values);

result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));

console.log(result)
```

the output will be :

```
{
  fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 1,
  insertId: 0,
  info: 'Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0',
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningStatus: 0,
  changedRows: 1
}
```

this way somehow makes it become a normal object to be accessed

so the object can be accessed like result.affectedRows, result.insertId, ...